# XNA WP7 accelerometer Controls

Tags: xna, accelerometer, xna-4.0

I am porting a game over to a XNA 4.0 WP7 project but am having some problems with controls. I am using the accelerometer to control movement but sometimes the ship will completely skip to another area of the screen. I have the code below for the controls.

```
    Accelerometer _motion;
    Vector2 accelReading = new Vector2();
    private float speed = 50.0f;

    //Initialize
    _motion = new Accelerometer();

    _motion.ReadingChanged += new EventHandler<AccelerometerReadingEventArgs>(AccelerometerReadingChanged);

    _motion.Start();

    //Method for Changed Readings
    public void AccelerometerReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
    {
        accelReading.X = (float)e.X;
        accelReading.Y = (float)e.Y;

        vel.X = accelReading.Y * speed;
        vel.Y = accelReading.X * speed;
    }

    //Update
     float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

     pos += vel * elapsed;

     vel *= 1 - elapsed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadingChanged` event is marked deprecated in WP 7.1 that's there was some reason and it might be reading errors use `CurrentValueChanged`.

If that do not help try WP7 using `Motion` class it is more accure

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.motion(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed over to use CurrentValueChanged but it is still having the same problem. When I move it will move from the top of the screen down to the bottom. Not sure what is causing this and also the direction of the sprite switches.

Comment: I think I know what might be wrong, try reduceing speed since it is 50  it may be to fast